# Removing the new line character from javascript and making the data come in single line

Tags: javascript, regex

I've the data like

1

2

3

4

after I replace I should get the data as `1234` or `1 2 3 4`.

I'm reading the content from one field and storing it one variable.
I'm assigning the replaced value to one more variable.

I've tried using

```
var justiread=comments.read();
var result=justiread.replace(new RegExp( "/\r?\n|\r/", "g" ), "");
```

even after replacing I'm getting the same as I've entered.

If i want to do the same thing repeatedly
say like 7 times. I'm using for loop but the same query is not working.
any help pls

```
  for(h=1;h<=7;h++){
    var addjusti=JUSTIFICATION.read(h);
    var addresult=addjusti.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ");

    }
```

but i'm unable to write it into the field

Anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `new RegExp`.  Just use the string replace method.

`justiread..replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"")`

The "g" switch is global replace, "m" means it should happen more than once.

See http://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/javascript-line-breaks.php

Comment: `m` means something a bit different than that.  Kinda totally different, in fact.  :P  Basically, it means that the string can be multiple lines, and `^` and `$` match at the beginning and end of each line.  If you don't have a `^` or `$` in the pattern, it doesn't much matter.

Comment: If i want to do the same thing repeatedly
say like 7 times. I'm using for loop but the same query is not working.
any help pls

Answer (score 1):

```
str.replace(/(\r|\n)/g,"")
```

should do the trick.

\r and \n are not always together (depends on EOL style... unix/windows etc).